# How to sync data between MongoDB's in a Cluster?

Tags: mongodb, nginx, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I'm a high school student. I implemented a spring boot application. It's deployed in AWS EC2. I'm using Nginx as my load balancer. My application is running on two different ec2 instances behind the load balancer both using their own MongoDB. How do I sync the data b/w the two DB's? Please pardon me for any mistake, I'm doing this for the first time and please feel free to point out mistakes in my design.

Comment: Are you able to build a replicaset between the two mongo instances ? (I don't know the AWS environment)

Comment: no. please explain me the process. Thanks